# How to set port for php project?

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

My php project by default has port:80, I need to make it any port above 1024.

I have multiple files in my project, when I try to make something like
`"myproject/item/1"` it responds with error 404 even if I have this URI in my routes.
 
On the other hand, when I start project by typing `php -S localhost:8050`, and do like `"myproject:8050/item/1"` everything works perfectly. I use method from some [dude in github](https://github.com/alecaddd/virtualhost) to create php projects, by default it copies `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`, where default port is *80.

I need to make first example `"myproject/item/1"` working properly

P.S. I don't want to change 000-default file, because I don't want all my projects to be broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For HTTP, browser by default is sending request to port 80, if you want run your project under another port you always need to specify that in request URI.

You need to create new configuration in /etc/apache2/sites-available eg. myproject.conf which may look like this:

```
Listen 8050
NameVirtualHost *:8050
<VirtualHost *:8050>    
        ServerName myproject
        ServerAlias www.myproject

        DocumentRoot /var/www/myproject

        <Directory /var/www/myproject>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

save, and enable your vhost by typing `a2ensite myproject.conf`, reload or restart apache and that's it.

Another way is create an alias in default configuration:

```
Alias /myproject "/var/www/myproject/"
<Directory /var/www/myproject>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride None
     Order allow,deny
     allow from all
</Directory>
```

That way, your project will be accessible by requesting like `http://{your_server_addr}/myproject` without specifying port.

Comment: should I delete the prev myproject.conf? and from sites-enabled too?

Comment: You don't need to. If you want to disable some configuration just type `a2dissite myproject.conf`, then myproject.conf disappear from sites-enabled but remain in sites-available if you need that later. Name of configuration doesn't matters, you can create new configuration in sites-available with name myproject1, myproject2 etc... and you can store all configurations for later purposes.

Comment: Thanks for ur help